# LVM DRBD Shared between nodes proxmox

Tags: lvm, high-availability, drbd, proxmox

Context :
I have proxmox cluster with the volume group shared with drbd for the VM - KVM.

I have a problem with drbd. Indeed, when a node disconnect, the associate link between the differents nodes is broken. Impacts are :

- Status drbd nodes : cs: WFConnection / cs: Standalone
- If we shall restart drbd and resync for the service is OK (cs: Connected), I do this actions :

  > I stop the running VMs (because : ERROR: Module drbd is in use)
  >   I disable the vg (with vgchange -an)
  >   I restart the drbd service and the resync running

The configuration is :

/etc/drbd.conf :

```
# You can find an example in  /usr/share/doc/drbd.../drbd.conf.example

include "drbd.d/global_common.conf";
include "drbd.d/*.res";
```

Global_common.conf:

```
global { usage-count no; }
common {
    protocol C;
    startup {
        degr-wfc-timeout 120;
#        become-primary-on proxmox001;
        become-primary-on both;
    }
    disk {
    }
    net {
        allow-two-primaries;
        after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
        after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
        after-sb-2pri disconnect;
    }
    syncer {
        verify-alg md5;
        rate 30M;
    }
}
```

R0.res :

```
resource r0 {
        protocol C;
        on proxmox001 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/mapper/pve-lv_data;
                address 192.168.0.1:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        on proxmox002 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/mapper/pve-lv_data;
                address 192.168.0.2:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
}
```

When a physical host have a instability, I lost the drbd link.

In normal time, /proc/drbd :

```
GIT-hash: 83ca112086600faacab2f157bc5a9324f7bd7f77 build by root@proxmox001, 2013-04-24 12:55:32
 0: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:421142 nr:55715 dw:8498959 dr:10994034 al:1144 bm:420 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:b oos:0
```

And while an instability, /proc/drbd return :

```
cs:Standalone or cs:WFConnection st:Secondary/Unknown
```

And when I would restart DRBD Sync, I have an error with UpToDate or

```
ERROR: Module drbd is in use proxmox
```

I try differents tests then Google suggested :

```
root@proxmox001:~# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "pve" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "drbdvg" using metadata type lvm2


root@proxmox001:~# vgchange -an /dev/drbdvg
  Can't deactivate volume group "drbdvg" with 1 open logical volume(s)


root@proxmox001:~# /sbin/vgchange -a y
  4 logical volume(s) in volume group "pve" now active
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "drbdvg" now active

root@proxmox001:~# cat /proc/drbd
version: 8.3.13 (api:88/proto:86-96)
GIT-hash: 83ca112086600faacab2f157bc5a9324f7bd7f77 build by root@proxmox001, 2013-04-24 12:55:32
 0: cs:WFConnection ro:Primary/Unknown ds:UpToDate/DUnknown C r-----
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:8523047 dr:11025118 al:1147 bm:421 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:b oos:8080

root@proxmox001:~# drbdadm connect all

root@proxmox001:~# drbdadm verify r0
0: State change failed: (-15) Need a connection to start verify or resync
Command 'drbdsetup 0 verify' terminated with exit code 11

root@proxmox001:~# cat /proc/drbd
version: 8.3.13 (api:88/proto:86-96)
GIT-hash: 83ca112086600faacab2f157bc5a9324f7bd7f77 build by root@proxmox001, 2013-04-24 12:55:32
 0: cs:WFConnection ro:Primary/Unknown ds:UpToDate/DUnknown C r-----
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:8523371 dr:11025534 al:1147 bm:421 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:b oos:8288

root@proxmox001:~# drbdadm secondary all
0: State change failed: (-12) Device is held open by someone
Command 'drbdsetup 0 secondary' terminated with exit code 11

root@proxmox001:~# drbdadm up r0
0: Failure: (124) Device is attached to a disk (use detach first)
Command 'drbdsetup 0 disk /dev/mapper/pve-lv_data /dev/mapper/pve-lv_data internal --set-defaults --create-device' terminated with exit code 10

root@proxmox001:~# service drbd stop
Stopping all DRBD resources:/dev/drbd0: State change failed: (-12) Device is held open by someone
ERROR: Module drbd is in use
.
root@proxmox001:~# drbdadm detach r0
0: State change failed: (-2) Need access to UpToDate data
Command 'drbdsetup 0 detach' terminated with exit code 17

root@proxmox001:~# vgchange -an /dev/drbdvg
  0 logical volume(s) in volume group "drbdvg" now active

root@proxmox001:~# service drbd stop
Stopping all DRBD resources:.

root@proxmox001:~# service drbd start
Starting DRBD resources:[ d(r0) s(r0) n(r0) ].
```

But I have always an production interrupt ...

Have you any solution for bypass this problems ?

Thanks very much !

EDIT :

If I replace the disk bloc in global_common file configuration as :

```
disk {
    fencing resource-only;
}
```

If I have any running VMs on once hosts, I need only restart drbd for rebuild the associate sync link.

But, if I have any runnings VMs on two or all hosts, I already same as top thread.

Thanks